# Tcl/Tk absolutely simple Hello World example fails - invalid command name "button"

Tags: button, tcl, tk-toolkit

I was trying to follow the tutorials/code-snippets on the [wiki Tcl lang page](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/The+Hello+World+program+as+implemented+in+Tcl%2FTk).

- But unfortunately, no matter, if I write the following code in a text file *hello_world.tcl*, as shown below:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/wish
button .hello -text "Hello, World!" -command { exit }
pack .hello
```

it gives the following error:

> $ tclsh hello_world.tcl 
>   invalid command name "button" 
>       while executing 
>   "button .hello -text "Hello, World!" -command { exit }" 
>      (file "hello_world.tcl" line 4)

---

- Or If I launch *tkcon* and repeat the same, I get this notice:

[image]

and upon pressing *retry*, I get this:

[image]

which is not what I want.

I just wanted a simple button with "Hello World" which upon getting clicked would close the window that was launched upon executing the script/command.

Googling the term *"Load Tk in Tcl"* or something similar produced nothing helpful.

How to get a working example in both cases?

Comment: Your shebang line has "wish" but you are specifically invoking the script with "tclsh". You could just make your script executable and then `./hello_world.tcl`

Comment: Thanks for the idea @glennjackman. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load Tk first, in other words:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/wish
package require Tk      ;# This line

button .hello -text "Hello, World!" -command { exit }
pack .hello
```

Comment: tatsächlich! ok, as per SO, I can accept the answer in only after ~5 min. p.s. and why in the world, do people in the TCL-universe go about writing *'hello world'* tutorials/examples with "includes" missing. You wouldn't do the same in C or python, for example.

Comment: @JoeyMallone That's a valid point. I'm not entirely sure myself, but that's the first time I've seen the "include" missing, then again, I haven't really looked into the tutorial that much, I learned most of my Tcl and Tk through working, existing solutions and by trying to understand and reproduce them.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Tcl files have been configured to be run by *tclsh* (which doesn't load the Tk package by default) and not *wish* (which does load Tk). The simplest fix is to explicitly load it at the start of your script with:

```
package require Tk
```

in all cases; then you'll either get things working as you expect or you'll get a clear failure that says that Tk couldn't be loaded (instead of a more mysterious message saying there's no `button` command).

---

Canonically, the recommended way of doing this would be:

```
#! /usr/bin/env wish

package require Tk

button .hello -text "Hello, World!" -command { exit }
pack .hello
```

as that allows for `wish` to be found on the path rather than being hard-coded to a particular location.